# Creating bookmarks of titles while scroll

Tags: jquery, html, gsap

Im making bookmarks on scroll. The concept: when you scroll and title reaches top of the screen script adds to left appropriative bookmark. Also Im using TweenMax to add some animation to this action. The problem now is that when I scroll back and forth around removed bookmarks its not alwayes added to left, throught 2-4 scrolls around it. Can understand why. Any ideas? [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/BKQdwO). And the code itself:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('h2').each(function(i){
        var elementOnTop = $(this).offset().top,
            winSize = $(window).scrollTop(),
            title = $(this).text(),
            textId = 'title-' + i++ ,
            linkTo = $(this).attr('id');

        if (winSize > elementOnTop) {
            if ($('.marks a:contains('+ title + ')').length == 0) {
                $('.marks').append('<a href="#' + linkTo + '" id="' + textId + '">' + title + '</a>');
                TweenMax.from('#'+textId, 1, {y: -20, opacity: 0, ease:Elastic.easeOut, force3D:false}, 0.2);
            }

        } else {
            TweenMax.to('#'+textId, 1, {y: -20, opacity: 0, ease:Back.easeOut, force3D:false,  onComplete:function(){(this.target).remove()}});

        }
    })
});
```